# Why isn't my StreamWriter saving to a textfile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have no issues reading the **fruits.txt** file with streamreader but writing to **newFruits.txt** seems to not work.

I run the code, with no errors, and then check the newFruits.txt file and see it still blank. I have my properties window of the newFruits.txt screenshot below if that helps. I checked other questions and they didn't seem similiar or understandable. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class FruityLoops
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading and sorting fruits...");
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;


        StreamReader fruitreader = new StreamReader("fruits.txt");
        string fruitList = fruitreader.ReadLine();
        char x = ',';
        string[] fruitArray1 = fruitList.Split(x);
        Array.Sort(fruitArray1);
        fruitreader.Close();

        StreamWriter fruitwriter = new StreamWriter("newFruits.txt");
        fruitwriter.WriteLine(fruitArray1);
        fruitwriter.Close();

    }
}
```

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njzOu.jpg) of my properties menu for the text file I am trying to write too. See any problems? Not sure if this is a settings problem or code issue.

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVuYk.jpg) of my fruits.txt file too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should pass one string line at a time when using 'WriteLine' method:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < fruitArray1.Length -1 ; i++)
        {
            fruitwriter.WriteLine(fruitArray1[i])
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works, but it saves the `newFruits.txt` file into bin\Debug or bin\Release directory where the program runs, *not* into `newFruits.txt` file that is part of your project.

Major comments:

1. The code will write `System.String[]` into the output file
2. `StreamWriter`s should be wrapped in `using` statements.

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not mention the element of the array.

you should give an index of the element you want to retrieve.

```
fruitwriter.WriteLine(fruitArray1[0]);
```

instead of

```
fruitwriter.WriteLine(fruitArray1);
```

2. Even though it writes, the program would ONLY Read and Write One line.

   Use loop to read and write line and close the StreamReader and StreamWriter after reading all the lines.